# I'm getting System.NullReferenceException on a variable that has a value

Tags: vb.net

I'm setting an array called aryRowOne() to {1, 6, 10, 15, 17, 22, 11} and when I try to use aryRowOne(1) it gives me back a NullReferenceException.

Firstly I tried having message boxes displaying values to show at what point it was broken and it made the problem make less sense. Right after the variable is given the value 6 it shows a message box that shows 6. Then it immediately crashes saying it has no value.

This is on the "Variables.vb" code file in the SetVars() sub

```
aryRowOne = {1, 6, 10, 15, 17, 22, 11}
```

which gives it a value.

Then it runs this

```
MessageBox.Show("aryRowOne(1) = " & aryRowOne(1))
```

Then on the "Debug.vb" form the CreateLog() sub is run when the user clicks a button. It shows a message box with this in it

```
MessageBox.Show("CreateLog() is running!")
```

to show it is running.

It Crashes when you reach this line

```
MessageBox.Show("aryRowOne(1) = " & VariablesTable.aryRowOne(1))
```

with...

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'
>
> VariablesTable.aryRowOne was Nothing.

It should have just not crashed. I'm writing it to a text file but it will not let me use the variable saying it is nothing.

Thanks to anyone who helps. This has stumped me for days.

Comment: You could make this easier by showing the code in one block that duplicates the problem.

Comment: My guess is that this is a scoping issue. Where and how is aryRowOne declared?

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you everything: `VariablesTable.aryRowOne` is not initialized. Maybe you have two variables with the same name in different scopes without realizing it? Do you have `Option Explicit On`? It also helps to step through with the debugger and have a look when this variable is set / cleared.